# An access violation (segmentation fault) was raised in your program

Tags: c, struct, scanf, fgets

how many students : 2 (it works fine)
how many students : 4 (it gives error "An access violation (segmentation fault) was raised in your program."

why it is happening with me, i have spent 4 hours but could not figure it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>


struct student 
{
    int rollno;
    char name[20];
};

int main()
{   
    int n,i,j;

    struct student detail[n];

    printf("how many students: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    fflush(stdin);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {            
        printf("enter student no.%d\n",(i));
        printf("Name: ");
        gets(detail[i].name);
        printf("Roll No: ");
        scanf("%d",&detail[i].rollno);
        fflush(stdin);
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Student no. %d Detail\n",(i+1));
        printf("Name:\t\t%s \nRoll No: \t%d\n",detail[i].name,detail[i].rollno);
    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is UB

Comment: Debugger................................

Comment: @MartinJames, in this case there is no need to debug, turning warnings on is enough :P

Answer (score 4):

In your code, the primary issue is

```
 int n,i,j;
 struct student detail[n];
```

you're using `n` uninitialized. It invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You need to move the definition of `detail[n];` *after* you have scanned the value from the user.

That said,

1. Check for the return value of `scanf()` to ensure success.
2. `gets()` is dangerous because it can cause buffer overflow. Use `fgets()` instead.
3. As per the standard, `fflush(stdin)` is UB, remove that.
4. `getch()` should be `getchar()`, if only `stdio.h` is included.

Comment: @AlterMann Thanks for the enhancement, added info from another angle :)

Comment: thanks mate i moved the defination of detail[n] after the scanned valud of 'n' and instead of fflush i used getchar().